# display: box; I have an issue with it

Tags: css

I have an issue with the `display: box;` property. (I know it is being deprecated, but flexbox barely works in any browsers at the moment).

When I re-size the browser and the window width becomes smaller than the width of the 4 `<li>` items, they don't cascade below each other. If I remove the `display:box;` stuff it works as it should, but then it isn't centered.

Is there anything that can be done about this? Or is it something that is an issue with the box property?

Live:
http://jsfiddle.net/ALGNq/2/

EDIT: I noticed that this is only firefox. However in Chrome the boxes 'stick' to the left hand side when the browser is too small.

Comment: Which css-module is this exactly?

Comment: I'm using CSS3 if that's what you mean? The closest would be [flex-box](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) module, I guess

Comment: the css3 specification consists of modules and i was interested in which module this is specified? I could not find any hint in the [flexbox module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/)

Comment: it's because box is being deprecated, it is from the 2009 spec but all browsers support the syntax.

Comment: Change `display:box;` with `display:inline;` and it should work fine

Comment: yup, then the content won't be vertically centered.